# RDLC report - Export to Word without tabluar format

Tags: c#, ms-word, rdlc

We are creating report using RDLC.

We have implemented using RDLC features and sub report functionality. There are around 10 different sections and its respective details .

It works fine and export to word also works.

As it is RDLC, it comes in tabular format. As per client requirements, We have hide all borders and data should be display in paragraphs and then export to Word. And then user will copy paste data from here and will use to create presentation.

Data should be display like this. For e.g.
When we export to word, table borders are not displayed but all comes in single table and it is cumbersome for end user to copy & paste as everything is in row and column.

```
Work Ref XXXX
Country of Origin XXX
Sponsor/Publisher/Owner XXX
Significant Contributors XXXX

XXX Library
Product Type XXX
Country XX
Identifier XXXX-XXXX
Release/Go-Live Date 01/08/2010

XXXX
Sub Title
Series
Format XXXX
Extent
Sales Rights World All Languages

Country XXX
XX Pub/Release Date 01/08/2010
XX Confirmation Status Confirmed
XX Classification XX
XX Sub Division XXX
XX Price Inc Tax 0.0
XX Tax Rate 0
XX Taxable % 100.00
XX Availability Status Available
```

Comment: It sounds like you would need to create separate report for export to Word.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you provide more details?

Comment: You would need to provide more information about your data to think of more detailed answer, but if your underlying data can be grouped by some criteria and all the details should fit into a page without any need for table on the page, then look into using List (with text boxes inside) instead of Tablix and page break by your group criteria. This should eliminate table formatting in Word.